# How to test a NodeJS UDP server with Artillery?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, udp, artillery

I have a basic dgram UDP server in NodeJS and I want to apply a load test to this server, using Artillery. However, I couldn't find a way to achieve this.

Artillery has engines such as HTTP, WebSocket, SocketIO and PlayWright. As I know, SocketIO and WebSocket TCP protocols. So, how do I do a UDP test with these engines?

*One of those engines or another implementation of UDP protocol in NodeJS are welcomed in my case.* Is there a way to achieve this?

My UDP server:

```
const UDP = require('dgram')
const server = UDP.createSocket('udp4')
const port = 2222

server.on('listening', () => {
  // Server address it’s using to listen

  const address = server.address()

  console.log('Listining to ', 'Address: ', address.address, 'Port: ', address.port)
})

server.on('message', (message, info) => {
  console.log('Message', message.toString())

  const response = Buffer.from('Message Received')

  //sending back response to client

  server.send(response, info.port, info.address, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Failed to send response !!')
    } else {
      console.log('Response send Successfully')
    }
  })
})

server.bind(port)
```

My Artillery config file:

```
config:
  target: http://localhost:2222
  phases:
    - duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 10 
      name: Warm up the API
    - duration: 30
      arrivalRate: 10
      rampTo: 15
      name: Ramp up to peak load

scenarios:
  - name: WebSocket Test
    engine: "socketio" # Enable the Socket.io engine
    flow:
      - emit:
          channel: "message"
          data: "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question on Artillery's Github Discussions: https://github.com/artilleryio/artillery/discussions/2189. Quoting from my answer there:

> The `socketio` engine which you're trying to use uses SocketIO's own communication protocol which is built on top of TCP, not UDP, AFAIK. So I don't think you'd be able to test UDP with it.
>
> However, Artillery is pretty extensible precisely for this reason and you can build your own engine to test anything with it. We have a blog post detailing how to do this yourself - https://www.artillery.io/blog/extend-artillery-by-creating-your-own-engines, as well as an [example](https://github.com/artilleryio/artillery/tree/main/examples/artillery-engine-example).
>
> Additionally, from a quick search on npm, you can see there's a few examples from the community, for instance:
>
> - https://github.com/flentini/artillery-engine-kafka
> - https://github.com/dwellir-public/artillery-engine-substrate
> - https://www.npmjs.com/package/artillery-engine-mqtt
> - etc